# Reference Error in API function call using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, api

```
formApp.controller('load', function ($scope, ApiCall, $window, $http) {
$window.onload = function () {
    alert("the page loaded and will now call the function");
    ApiCall.GetApiCall("signOn", "GetSingleSignOn").success(function (data) {
        alert("successful call to singleSignOn, GetSingleSignOn");
        var data = $.parseJSON(JSON.parse(data));
        $scope.apiGetInfo = data;
        alert("successful call to singleSignOn, GetSingleSignOn");
        alert(data);
    });
};
```

This code works fine up to the var data- $.parseJson(JSON.parse(data));

I looked at some examples of how to do this in the Controller online and they all looked this way with $.parseJSON(JSON.parse(data)). 
It gives me: **ReferenceError: $ is not defined**

Not sure why as every example I looked at to call an API Controller in Angular showed this way.

Comment: It's JQuery, try https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson

Comment: Why are you trying to parse an object? `JSON.parse()` will return an object; no need to parse it again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the $.parseJSON. remove it and leave the JSON.parse intact:

```
var data = JSON.parse(data);
```

If you want to use JQuery ($) you have to import the script.

UPDATE:

if you want to redirect to an `URL` you can use $window:

```
$window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
```

Comment: Thanks! Another question, the JSON parses out an HTML address, how can I in the controller go to that HTML page?

Comment: Thank you good sir I actually found that out right after I posted the comment, that's a piece of my project that is completed with this bit of information!